# Referencing a specific form element from inside a module

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, module-pattern

I'm trying to figure out how to reference a form inside of a module.

The module looks like this:

```
const UserShows = (function(){

  const saveShowToDashboard = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const $saveShowForm = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $saveShowForm.children('.save-show-btn').val('Saved');
    }, 500);
    const showInfo = $(this).children('.save-show-checkbox').val();
    const parsedShowInfo = JSON.parse(showInfo);
    const _csrf = $(this).children('.csrf').val();
    const artistName = parsedShowInfo.artist;
    const data = {
      showInfo: parsedShowInfo,
      _csrf: _csrf,
    };
    console.log(data);
    $.post('/artists/' + artistName, data, function(res) {
      if (res === '/login') {
        window.location = res;
      }else{
        console.log(res);
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    callSaveShowToDashboard: function(evt){
      return saveShowToDashboard(evt);
    }  
  }

})();

// Call saveShowToDashboard on click
$('.save-show').on('submit', UserShows.callSaveShowToDashboard);
```

The problem that I'm having is that I can't figure out how to reference the specific save-show form that's being submitted (there are several on the page; each one corresponding to an artist tour date).

Before I decided to put this function inside of the UserShows module, I was able to use $(this) to reference the specific form, but since the form is no longer the direct caller of the function, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that with JQuery you can refer to the element that triggered an event by using **event.target**. So if I rewrite the code like this, it works:

```
const saveShowToDashboard = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const $saveShowForm = $(event.target);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $saveShowForm.children('.save-show-btn').val('Saved');
    }, 500);
    const showInfo = $saveShowForm.children('.save-show-checkbox').val();
    const parsedShowInfo = JSON.parse(showInfo);
    const _csrf = $saveShowForm.children('.csrf').val();
    const artistName = parsedShowInfo.artist;
    const data = {
      showInfo: parsedShowInfo,
      _csrf: _csrf,
    };
    console.log(data);
    $.post('/artists/' + artistName, data, function(res) {
      if (res === '/login') {
        window.location = res;
      }else{
        console.log(res);
      }
    });
  };
```